# How do I customize my website post URL in PHP

Tags: php, url, string-literals

All posts are in the posts table. I display each post on the web page the posts are identified by random numbers from the database (ex: 10110501 means post number 1 and so on.). Now, when a visitor click a post excerpt I want the post to display with the URL like this: [www.example.com/posts/10110501](http://www.example.com/posts/10110501) this will display post number 1 from the database to the single post page. I do not want the URL to have ? symbol. How can I achieve this?

Comment: This question has a broad range of answers and may not be specific enough to get help here.  The most commonly used mechanism to achieve this is using URL rewriting.  The exact mechanism will depend upon the deployment platofrm (Apache, IIS, etc.)

Comment: How do I perform this URL rewrite on an Apache Server  @Martin?

Answer (score 1):

Under posts directory you can add an index.php and also an '.htaccess' to rewrite any url to index.php

after successfull rewrtie rule all your posts request will hit that index.php and on that index.php you can get the url with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

and then split the array take the random number and search it on database..

[Sample '.htaccess' with rewrite rule](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use  `.htaccess` reWrite Rules.

Suppose you want to have [www.yourdomain.com/profile?id=user-unique-name](http://www.yourdomain.com/profile?id=user-unique-name)
as [www.yourdomain.com/profile/user-unique-name](http://www.yourdomain.com/profile/user-unique-name)
Then in your `.htaccess` files you can write the following rules

```
RewriteEngine On
 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
 
RewriteRule ^users/(\d+)*$ ./profile.php?id=$1
```

For references please  [read here more](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049)

Comment: Thank you first of all. I'm  new to configuring .htaccess file. please explain what the last line of code is saying. I do not understand what "users" is in the rule for. please explain thanks again.